# Using multiple Relying Trust Parties on same ADFS 3.0 from one ASP.NET Web API

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, adfs

**Environment:**

- ADFS 3.0 (on SQL Server 2012) without device registration service

  - We defined a Relying trust party in ADFS with a TokenLifetime of 1440 minutes (1 day).
- ASP.NET Web Api configured to work with OWIN
- OAuth2
- Web Api which is used by a Windows Store App (8.1 / 10)

**Current situation:**

We got the authentication flow working between App, Web-api and ADFS with OAuth2. In the web-api in the startup class in App_Start\Startup.Auth we have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
    new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]

        }
    });
}
```

In the `web.config` we configured the `appsettings`:

```
<add key="ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint" value="https://adfs.service.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
<add key="ida:Audience" value="http://orderapi.service.com" />
```

**Wanted situation:**

When some important endpoints are used by the app we have the demand, that is less than 7 minutes ago that the user has authenticated/logged in. For the other less important endpoints this is not an issue, once a day is enough.

Our initial taught is to create an extra Relying Trust Party in ADFS with a different Token-LifeTime (7 minutes). Also at endpoint level we define two different URL in de Web-api:

- Long Token-lifetime --> every endpoint which may be used with a long Token-Lifetime starts with https://webapi.service.com/api_long/.... (--> https:  //webapi.service.com/api_long/Order/Get)
- Short Token-lifetime --> every endpoint which needs a short Token-Lifetime starts with https://webapi.service.com/api_short/...  (-->https:  //webapi.service.com/api_short/Order/Post)

**Question / Problem:**

- Is it possible to work with 2 Relying Trust Parties on the same ADFS from one Web-api?

  - If possible, how do you register the two Relying Trust Parties in the startup-class?
  - How do you tell the action of the controller which Relying Trust Party it has to use?
- If it is NOT possible to work with 2 Relying Trust Parties on the same ADFS from one Web-api, will be there another solution which can help us?

  - Mine own alternative is making 2 Web-api’s, one for the long and one for the short. But somehow I don’t find that an elegant solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.